# Tracking Remote Access

Tags: windows-7, networking, logging, remote-access, windows-domain

If someone with Domain Admin credentials accesses your PC by using `\\Computername\C$` is this "access" logged anywhere?  I.E. the date/time and possibly computer name it occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, everything is logged under security logs but there are so many logs under security (eventviewer). Having said that, information (date/time and computer name) can be easily checked if someone is familiar with this.